# Remove all less than symbols within a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains "less than"  symbols `<`:

```
col1 <- c(1,5,"<4",3,2,9)
col2 <- c(1,7,"<3",1,0,"<9")
df <- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

I tried to remove them using:

```
df%>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~recode(.x, "<" = "")))
```

but nothing happens.
Can anyone update the code to remove the less than symbols?

Answer (score 3):

Use `gsub` instead of `recode`:

```
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~gsub("<", "", .x)))
```

If you want to transform the columns to numeric as well, use

```
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(gsub("<", "", .x))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one-line `tidyverse` solution that doesn't use regular expressions:

```r
purrr::map_df(df, readr::parse_number)

# A tibble: 6 × 2
   col1  col2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     5     7
3     4     3
4     3     1
5     2     0
6     9     9
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R, you can use `lapply`:

```
df[] <- lapply(df[], gsub, pattern = "<", replace = "")
```

Output:

```
#   col1 col2
# 1    1    1
# 2    5    7
# 3    4    3
# 4    3    1
# 5    2    0
# 6    9    9
```

This seems to be a bit faster, if that matters:

```
# just replacing, ignoring other conversions for apples-to-apples
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  lapply = lapply(df[], gsub, pattern = "<", replace = ""),
  sapply = sapply(df[1:2], gsub, pattern = '<|>', replacement=''),
  map_df = purrr::map_df(df, readr::parse_number),
  mutate = dplyr::mutate(df, across(everything(), ~gsub("<", "", .x)))
)

# Unit: microseconds
#   expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
# lapply    37.008    45.3630    57.0735    56.1910    66.1095    99.398   100 a  
# sapply    85.414   116.3175   134.3841   130.5705   146.6320   312.211   100 a  
# map_df 11655.005 12276.7180 12695.4693 12627.5100 13079.8065 14175.207   100  b 
# mutate  2924.774  3260.0175  3672.1869  3524.5660  3715.2880 20122.156   100   c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `gsub` them away and convert columns to numeric in one go. If you have more stuff to remove, you may want to use sort of a dictionary in brackets, e.g. `'[<>]'`. Note that then special characters need to be escaped, e.g. `'[<>\\%]'`.

```
> df[1:2] <- sapply(df[1:2], gsub, pattern='<', replacement='') |> type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
> df
  col1 col2
1    1    1
2    5    7
3    4    3
4    3    1
5    2    0
6    9    9
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(col1 = c("1", "5", "<4", "3", "2", "9"), col2 = c("1", 
"7", "<3", "1", "0", "<9")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```